# Displaying frames from 2 separate videos according to timestamps stored in a text file

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I have videos from 2 cameras recorded such that I get timestamps for each frame in a text file for both the videos feed recorded.

Now I want to display the frames from both cameras side by side in a single frame but according to the time stored in the text file. How should I go about doing that?

Here is a sample timestamp data for videos recorded from *camera 1* and *camera 2*

```
Camera1             Camera2
0.200000047         0.000000000
33.515000047        33.315000000
```

Now according to the timestamp file, frame 1 of *camera 1* should be visible at 0.2 sec and frame 1 of *camera 2* should be visible at 0.0 sec (start of the video). Frame 2 of *camera 2* then coming at 33.315 sec and frame 2 of *camera 1* coming at 33.315000047 sec.

I am getting stuck on 'how to display frames at specific time?'

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to play them back in "real time"? As in, ~33.32 s of real time should elapse before the second frame of camera 1 is displayed.

Comment: yes, frame 1 should remain for 33.32s before the next frame comes in

Comment: sort the timestamps and update only next image (the one of the other camera isnt updated) if your rendering is fast enough. Of not, use fixed rendering timestamps and choose the latest previous  (or the closest maybe in future) frames of both cameras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this outline should do the job:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

# ...

CAMERA_1 = 0
CAMERA_2 = 1

def load_timestamps(camera):
    pass # Implement this

def get_next_frame(camera):
    pass # Implement this

# ...    

timestamps = [
    load_timestamps(CAMERA_1)
    , load_timestamps(CAMERA_2)
    ]

start_time = None

frame_index = [0, 0]
video_done = [False, False]

# Make those default blank images the size of your video...
# Adjust number of channels if you're using grayscale
image =  [np.zeros((100,100,3),np.uint8)] * 2

while True:
    real_time = time.time()
    if start_time is None: # First iteration only
        start_time = real_time
    current_ts = real_time - start_time
    print("ts=%0.3f s" % current_ts)

    # Advance both cameras up to current_ts
    for i in [CAMERA_1, CAMERA_2]:
        while True:
            # Get timestamp of the frame at current position
            current_index = frame_index[i]
            if current_index >= len(timestamps[i]):
                video_done[i] = True
                break # End of the video
            video_ts = timestamps[i][current_index]
            if current_ts < video_ts:
                break # The frame is in future, stop
            # The frame is in the past or present
            print("  camera %d: frame %d" % (i+1, frame_index[i]))
            image[i] = get_next_frame(i)
            frame_index[i] += 1

    cv2.imshow("Output", np.hstack([image[0], image[1]]))
    cv2.waitKey(20) # Max 50 FPS, but probably slower

    if video_done[CAMERA_1] and video_done[CAMERA_2]:
        break
```

We have a loop that runs periodically (approximately every 20ms, using the sleep in `cv2.waitKey(...)`).

On every iteration we measure the time offset from the first iteration, which gives us a 0-based timestamp.

Then we "seek" each video by reading the frames and advancing the index to our timestamp list, until both videos have caught up.

Finally we display the most recent frames from each video side by side.

---

## Example

Let's imagine we have 3 frames for *camera 1* at timestamps

```
[ 1.0, 3.0, 5.0 ]
```

[image: camera_1]

and 3 frames for *camera 2* at timestamps

```
[ 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 ]
```

[image]

We set the wait time to be 0.5 seconds to keep this short.

Tracing the program we get the following output:

```
ts=0.000 s
ts=0.500 s
ts=1.000 s
  camera 1: frame 0
ts=1.500 s
ts=2.000 s
  camera 2: frame 0
ts=2.500 s
ts=3.000 s
  camera 1: frame 1
  camera 2: frame 1
ts=3.500 s
ts=4.000 s
  camera 2: frame 2
ts=4.500 s
ts=5.000 s
  camera 1: frame 2
```

and the video, with snapshots taken each steps looks like

[image]

Note: First frame at t=0.0 s and last frame at t=5.0s.

---

## Possible Improvements

- When there's a longer gap between frames, wait longer
- Only update display when at least one of the images/frame indexes changes
- Wait on timer event instead of sleeping (would most likely need custom GUI)

Comment: what exactly is the get_frame(i) doing? I tried implementing after my basic understanding of the code

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cam1.mp4')`
`cap.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_index)`
`ret, frame = cap.read()`

`return frame`